# How to debug stored procedure when it is executed by a .NET application?

Tags: .net, sql-server, debugging

I have a stored procedure, I can put breakpoints in it then execute it manually to debug it. However, this does not suffice. I would like to be able to debug it when a .NET(C#) application invokes it, in other words debug it during runtime of .NET application.

Is it possible, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to debug from .net application, What the deifferents from regular SQL excutaion? if you want to see the parameters values - The most simple way is to catch the SP executaion via the SQL Profiler

Comment: Never tried it myself but "In Solution Explorer, right-click the project (not the solution) and open the Property pages. Click Configuration Properties in the tree and then click to select the SQL Server Debugging check box on the Debugging page to enable stored procedure debugging." [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316549/how-to-debug-stored-procedures-in-visual-studio-net)

Comment: @HoneyBadger I've tried that route myself, and all I can say is "good luck with that".  Numerous server configurations have to be put in place.

Comment: Your best chance of success in this regard is to have your database as its own database project, deploy it on a `localdb` instance, configure the solution to have multiple startup projects, and set breakpoints from there. Invoking a breakpoint on a "real" server is possible, but is so involved and error-prone that it's basically not worth doing. You're better off capturing the stored procedure invocation with Profiler and analyzing things from there.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, neither how you invoke your stored procedure from .NET to SQL: linq + Entity Framework? OleDB? Other?

If you want to debug it from the SQL side, it would do the same as you seems to already do, through SQL Server Management Studio for example.

From the .Net side, what you can basically check first, is what parameters are sent to your Stored Procedure, then use the same in SSMS.